# how to get images' hog features in tensorflow pipeline mechanism?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow

when use tensorflow reads lots of image data ,we use pipeline mechanism:

1.get the list of filenames and labels;
2.filename list shuffle and set epochs;
3.filename queue;
4.image reader and decoder;
5.set batches or example queues;

I know how to get image hog features using opencv or skimage etc. but how to do it with tensorflow?

thank you!

Comment: There seem to be some implementations floating around, e.g. https://github.com/codeminders/tfcv. Do those work for you?

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thanks!!